# how to download yahoo finance content URL in matlab?

Tags: matlab, yahoo-finance

```
urlstring = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/M/key-statistics?p=M';
urlwrite(urlstring, 'stats.html');
```

This yields the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> urlwrite at 134
Error downloading URL.
```

Comment: That command works fine in R2020a. Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: That (or using urlget) would only get you the web page, but as the date is fetched from a server using Javascript which Matlab can not run, you would not be able to use this approach unless yahoo finance had some open API for Json or XML export.